# How to create query who will be sum or not values from tables

Tags: sql, doctrine

I have table like this

```
Table1 
ID   Name  Value fk_table
1    edd   3      1 
2    tom   1      2
3    emi   2     NULL
```

And second table

```
Table2
ID VALUE
1   3
2   3
```

How to create query who will be sum value from table1 and table2 if is a foreign key, or will output only value from table1 if isn't fk

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQuery('SELECT t1.name, SUM(t1.value as value +t2.value) 
                                   FROM AcmeBlogBundle:Table1 t1
                                   LEFT JOIN t1.table2 t2')
                    ->execute();
```

I want result like this

```
edd 6
tom 5
emi 2
```

I use doctrine and Symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You haven't specified the conditions you are joining on

2 - SUM function does not work like that - it sums aggregate on whole column, you just need a +

3 - Using COALESCE to ensure the missing values are replaced with 0

```
SELECT T1.Name, COALESCE(T1.VALUE,0) + COALESCE(T2.VALUE,0) 
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.fk_table = T2.ID
```

[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20410/4) (SQL Server in example, but should also work fine with other SQL flavors)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that NULL 'zaps the life out of everything'. Adding it to any other value results in NULL. You should use `COALESCE(t2.value, 0)` to ensure it results a valid integer that doesn't interfere with the sum.